# How to print diff for retry until with failing matcher in Karate?

Tags: karate

I have a following request:

```
Given url myUrl
* path '/v1/endpoint'
* configure retry = { count: 10, interval: 10000 }
* retry until responseStatus == 200 && response.someArray[5].someInt == 55
When method get
```

When the retry condition is never met, I get only a `too many retry attempts: 10` log.

What is missing for debugging purpose, is a full matcher diff print like for regular matchers

```
When method get
Then match response.someArray[5].someInt == 55
```

```
match failed: EQUALS
  $ | not equal (NUMBER:NUMBER)
  55
  12345
```

Is that possible, at least for the very last iteration of the retry?

Comment: possibly needs framework changes, do consider contributing code or influencing someone who can